# My Front end does not call my back end no api is called

Tags: javascript, axios, cors

so basically i have cloned the repo and when i try to run the app using npm start it successfully run but it does not fetch the api from back end IDK why it gives me two error cors Error with the products endpoint it fetches when the app load and the another error it gives 403 Forbidden

```
//import 'whatwg-fetch';
import axios from 'axios';
import { SERVER_URL } from './util/api.config';
//import { getLocalStorageValue } from '../../components/common/util/util';
/**
 * Parses the JSON returned by a network request
 *
 * @param  {object} response A response from a network request
 *
 * @return {object}          The parsed JSON from the request
 */
function parseJSON(response) {
  // if (response && response.headers) {
  //   if (response.headers["content-type"] === "application/octet-stream") {
  //     if (response.config.url.includes('api/v1/customer/avatar') || response.config.url.includes('api/v1/transactions/export') || response.config.url.includes('api/v1/transactions/export/single')) // for user profile image and export transaction
  //       return response.data && response.data();
  //     else
  //       response.data && response.data.text();
  //   }
  // }
  if (response && response.code === 401) {
    return {
      code: 401,
      message: "Session Expired"
    }
  }
  if (response && response.code === 419) {
    return {
      code: 419,
      message: "Session Expired"
    }
  }
  if (response.status === 500) {
    if (response && response.data) {
      return response.data;
    }
    else {
      return {
        error: {
          code: 500,
          description: "Internal Server Error"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (response && response.code === 204 || response && response.code === 205) {
    return null;
  }
  return response && response.data;
}

/**
 * Checks if a network request came back fine, and throws an error if not
 *
 * @param  {object} response   A response from a network request
 *
 * @return {object|undefined} Returns either the response, or throws an error
 */
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }
  if (response.status === 500) {
    return response;
  }
  if (response.status === 403) { // for un authorized messages 
    return {
      code: 401,
      message: "Session Expired"
    }
  }

  if (response.status === 400) {
    return response;
  }

  if (response.status === 401) {
    return {
      code: 401,
      message: "Session Expired"
    }
  }
  if (response.status === 419) {
    return {
      code: 419,
      message: "Session Expired"
    }
  }

  const error = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
}

/**
 * Requests a URL, returning a promise
 *
 * @param  {string} url       The URL we want to request
 * @param  {object} [options] The options we want to pass to "fetch"
 *
 * @return {object}           The response data
 */
export default function request(url, options, auth) {
  //const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
  if (options.isLocal === true) {
    url = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${url}`;
  }
  else {
    if (options.accountOpeningType === "dob") {
      url = `${SERVER_URL}/digital/onboard/${url}`
    }
    else {
      url = `${SERVER_URL}/rda/${url}`;
    }
  }
  if (options.body) {
    if (options.contentType === "multipart/form-data") {
      let data = {};
      data = new FormData();
      for (var item in options.body) {
        data.append(item, options.body[item])
      }
      options.data = data;
    }
    else {
      options.data = options.body;
    }
  }
  if (options.contentType == "multipart/form-data") {
    options.headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.get('token')}`,
      'PLATFORM' : 'WEB'
    };
  }
  else if (auth && auth.get('token')) { //LOGIN_CHANGES
    if (url.includes('upload/document') || url.includes('rda/document?id') || url.includes('digital/onboard/document?id')) {
      options.responseType = options.isPdf ? "blob" : "arraybuffer";
    }
    else {
      options.responseType = "json";
    }
    options.headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.get('token')}`,
      'PLATFORM' : 'WEB'
    };
  }
  else {
    if (options.actionType && options.actionType === "LOGOUT") { // DONE because user not to feel any delay in logout
      options.headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${options.data && options.data.get('token')}`,
        'PLATFORM' : 'WEB'
      };
      options.responseType = "json";
      options.data = {}
    }
    else {
      options.responseType = "json";
      options.headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'PLATFORM' : 'WEB'
      };
    }
  }
  options.url = url;
  options.timeout = 95000; // in miliseconds
  const resAxios = axios({
    ...options,
    validateStatus: function (status) {
      return status >= 200 && status <= 700;
    }
  }).then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then((response) => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (error && error.__CANCEL__ === true) {
        return {
          code: 1,
          message: "Request Cancelled"
        }
      }
      else {
        return {
          code: 0,
          message: "Connection Failed"
        }
      }
    });
  return resAxios;
  // return axios(({...options})
  //   .then(checkStatus)
  //   .then(parseJSON)
  //   .then((response) => {
  //     return response
  //   }))
}
```

this is my request.js file in which all the request to a backend initiated by this file

and my cors error says the error is in the resAxios variable

[Here is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTmMp.png)

I try to resolve by using chat gpt cors error and reviewing all the code in the request.js file but i won't find any thing that causes this error

Comment: CORS is something you configure at the server side, wherever that "products" happens to be located. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: so you think this is error from a back end ?

Comment: Yes. [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) may indicate that you're simply not supposed to request for `products` directly, and something is missing.

Comment: options.headers = {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.get("token")}`,
      PLATFORM: "WEB",
    };

or I explicitly add a accessControlAllow origin here?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api url' from origin 'localhost:5565' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. this is what i am getting so i need to pass Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from a back end

Answer (score 0):

If you use ExpressJS, you can addapt this:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Access to all
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"),
  // or limit access example (all dns you want)
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "example.com example.fr"),
  // Accept or allow the Content-Type request from Origin
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"),
  next(),
}),
```

It's just an example all depend of what you are using: **ExpressJS, Apache, Nginx...**

Like its says in comment, see **HTTP Headers** here:

[Mozilla Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

[Mozilla HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

[Mozilla CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)